# Have lived vs. Have been living

Tags: present-perfect

What is the difference between the followings?

> A. I *have been living* here for 5 years.
>
> B. I *have lived* here for 5 years.

Am I correct that these two represent the same event, but A emphasizes the continuity of living while B simply states a fact that you lived there from 5 years ago to the present?

Is it true that the difference in present perfect and present perfect continuous is whether a speaker intends to emphasize continuity or a fact?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The difference between your two examples isn’t great, but, depending on context, A might give a slightly stronger impression than B that the speaker will continue to live there.

The difference is more apparent in a pair such as:

> I’ve been reading your book.
>
> I’ve read your book.

The first suggests that the speaker is still reading it, whereas the second suggests that the reader has finished it.

Comment: Can you say - I have lived in the USA for 5 years, standing in the center of Berlin ?

Comment: I have been in the US for 5 years. is it right?

Comment: "whereas the second suggests that the reader has finished it." - but isn't it against the concept of present perfect that the action is still continue? Wouldn't past perfect will be used in case that you not lived there any more?

Comment: The accepted answer really should have examples with similar time clauses.

Answer (score 6):

The present continuous tense is normally used to express an action that is *temporary* in nature. If you were to say: **I'm living in a flat**, some might interpret it as not being a long-term arrangement.

Likewise, the present perfect continuous conveys continuity and can emphasize its transitory state.

> *I have been living here for five years.*

The above suggests that the person could one day change residence, it implies it is not a permanent situation whereas the [present perfect tense](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/present-tense/present-perfect) is more suitable for lengthier periods of time. Contrast the earlier sentence with this one:

> *Anne has lived here all her life*.

Anne is 65 years old, she has never changed residence and is unlikely to ever move. The action is not only continuous but it also suggests permanence.

Comment: "all her life" adds the implication of continuity, so it doesn't make the best example.  Here's another example to consider: "I have lived in Mexico for 5 years and I have lived in Canada for 5 years."  By your answer it'd imply I'm I'm stilling living in Canada and  Mexico.

Answer (score 6):

The following interpretation is taken from the book *Common Mistakes in CAE. Cambridge University Press by Debra Powell*.

We use the simple aspect of tenses for actions which we think are:

**• finished:** I've done my homework. (the homework is finished)

**• permanent:** I've lived in England for 10 years. I've worked for this company for most of that time. (I think I will remain in England and continue to work for the same company)

We use the continuous aspect of tenses for actions which we think are:

**• unfinished or in progress:** I've been doing my homework. (it isn't finished yet)

**• temporary:** I've been living in England for six months. I've been working as an au pair. (I think I will leave England one day- my job is temporary)

Comment: I was about to dismiss this as a repeat of earlier answers. **But it adds an attributed supporting reference.**

Answer (score 2):

*I have been living here for 5 years* can only be continuous and current.

*I have lived here for 5 years* can be continuous and current, or total period of time and current or total period of time but not current.

Comment: In the case of "total period of time but not current", wouldn't you say _I had lived here for 5 years_?

Comment: I think the only way I'd say *I have lived here for 5 years* and mean that I had lived here for a total of 5 years some time in the past, is if I was in an argument and somebody said, "Try living here for 5 years" to which I might reply (with strong emphasis on the *have*), "I **have** lived here for 5 years."

Comment: @ekbass: You're right, but it would probably then be _I had lived **there** for 5 years_.

Comment: I agree with Barrie here. I'd say either "_I **did** live **here** for 5 years 20 years ago_" or "_I **lived here** for 5 years 20 years ago_", but "_I **had lived there** for 5 years_".

Comment: I have been living here for 5 years and I have lived here for 5 years are essentially the same in this context. You can not say - I have lived here all my life, ( or for 5 years ) at the same time being in another country. Both tenses indicate that a speaker has spent 5 years somewhere and at the time of speaking is physically there.

Comment: @Beqa I think you're point is specific to the case where "here" is used (as a opposed to an arbitrary place "I have live in Paris for 5 years." so the conclusion won't generalize.

Comment: For "I had lived here for 5 years." the use of past tense "had" indicates the relevance is being applied to a past time.   

Example had: "Once I had lived in Mexico for 5 years and Canada for 3 years I was ready to pick one."
Example have: "I have lived in Mexico for 5 years and I have lived in Canada for 3 years so now I am ready to pick one."

Answer (score -1):

*Unfinished* (continuous) and *permanent* (perfect) are in terms of living somewhere, since the future is not known, mostly same. If there is a plan of leaving (*finishing)* then the present continuous be more precise.