# Difference between I have lived or I have been living?

Tags: grammar

1) I have lived here since 2006

2) I have been living here since 2006.

What's the difference between the above cases? Are there different conditions to use each one of them? Or can they be used interchangeably?  I have already read this answer but what I want is simple answer and explanation that whether I have lived here since 2006 mean I am not living here now or I am still living.No doubt this answer is well explained but I am unable to understand it completely that's why I said earlier that I want easy explanation.
Hope you get my problem now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have lived vs. Have been living](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84898/have-lived-vs-have-been-living) (see Mari-Lou A's answer, and Barrie's for cases where a different main verb is used).

Comment: You might be more comfortable on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Using 'since [a date]' makes both sentences mean that you are still living there.

Answer (score 1):

> **I  have  lived  here  since 2006**
>
> **I have  been  living  here  since  2006.**

The  first  sentence  may  mean  that  you  have been living   there  since  2006 and  you are  still  living  there  and  may be  living  in the  future  too.

It  also  may  mean  that  you  have  lived there  since  2006   but  you  are  not  living  there.You  have  prabably  gone  to  somewhere  else.

The  second  categorically  means  that  you have  been  living  there  since  2006  and  you are  still  living  there.

So  if  you  are  particular  about  your  living  there  now, it  is  better  to say  **I  have  been  living  there  since 2006**

Comment: Should I really say “I have lived in Illinois since 1969” if I moved to California in 1981?

Comment: It  is not necessary.Present  perfect  means  two  things.